# Regular expression to perform named capture of user agent string variations

Tags: regex, pcre

I am trying to come up with a regular expression capable of capturing an entire user agent string as a single named group logged in one of the 2 following formats:

```
Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/5.0)
"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"
```

Note: When the second format is used, I don't want the quotes captured.

Using some variation on alternation seems to be the right approach here, so I thought something like this would work:

```
(?:"(?<user_agent>[^"]+)")|(?<user_agent>[^\s]+)
```

But it doesn't.  It doesn't seem to capture anything.  I'm clearly missing something here.

The following almost works -- at least it captures something -- but it doesn't perform a named capture (which I need):

```
(?:"([^"]+)")|([^\s]+)
```

Other notes (in case it matters):

- I'm using a PCRE engine.
- Both user agent string variations will have a single leading and a single trailing space.
- The tool I've been using for testing (which I've found to be very reliable) lives here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

This seems like it should be *really* simple, but I suspect I'm misunderstanding how the alternation works between named groups.

---

### Update

By way of clarification, there will also be content before and after the user agent string, like so:

```
some-content-before Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/5.0) some-content-after
some-content-before "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)" some-content-after
```

This is important because the user agent string named capturing group shouldn't capture either the content before or the content after, because they will each be captured via their own named capturing group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The named capture doesn't work because by default the PCRE engine doesn't accept the same named capture more than 1 time. But you can change this behaviour with the `(?J)` modifier, example:

```
(?J)(?:"(?<user_agent>[^"]+)")|(?<user_agent>\S+)
```

Another way is to use the branch reset feature `(?|...(..)...|...(..)...)` where the "two capture groups" are in reality a unique capture group in the several version of the alternation:

```
(?|"(?<user_agent>[^"]+)"|(?<user_agent>\S+))
```

Note that the implementation of gskinner is incomplete, but you can see the result with this tester: http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/

In fine, you can avoid the problem of duplicate named captures (for your example string) with these patterns:

```
("?)(?<user_agent>[^"]+|\S+)\1
```

or

```
(?<user_agent>[^"\r\n]+)
```

Comment: Thanks @Casimir! That was great feedback!  In light of the update/clarification I added to the initial problem, your most fitting solution was to use `(?|"(?<user_agent>[^"]+)"|(?<user_agent>\S+))` for capturing each user agent string variation.  And here's a regex that works with the example provided in my update: `(?<content_before>[^\s]+) (?|"(?<user_agent>[^"]+)"|(?<user_agent>\S+)) (?<content_after>[^\s]+)`. And thanks for the link to the alternative tool!  I'll use that from now on.  ...at least until I find something better. :)